# Driver upgraded but eclipse not being able to detect the device

Tags: android, eclipse, driver, target

I am trying to run an android application on an Acer Z120. But Eclipse is not detecting it. When trying to run the applicatio, I keep having the error "No compatible targets were found". I installed the driver from the site http://www.acer.fr/ac/fr/FR/content/drivers/4658;-;Z120. But it didn't fix the problem. I checked if the driver needs t be upgraded using the devices manager (Computer Mangager), and it is upgraded.
I thought that maybe it is because of the target, But my application is running with target 18, as you can see in the manifest :

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

and the device is Android 4.3 (API 18) so it should be working...

Any ideas why eclipse is still not detecting the device ?

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try

1)Is USB debugging on?

2)Can you access it as a file system?  If not, then its still a windows problem

3)Try switching from PTP to MTP for file transfer mode, and back again if needed

4)try running adb kill-server, then adb devices from the command line

5)Try killing adb via task manager, then restart it via adb devices